# Simple query in mySql - probably subquery and joins (intermediate)

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have 2 tables:

- 'clients' with columns 'client_id' and 'name'
- 'shops' with columns 'id', 'shop_name' and 'active' (enum y/n)

I want to create a query which will give me all of the client's names, + first of their shop_name which is set as active ('y'). If there is non - just give it as a null, but I need to have all of the clients names.

So basically I want to select all of the clients and check if they have an active shop and if so - assign first of them to the proper client.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT c.name
     , s.shop_name 
  FROM clients AS c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN shops AS s  
    ON s.id = c.client_id 
 WHERE s.active='y'
```

But it's not working - it's only giving me clients with active shops, forgetting about the other ones.

I'm thinking about subquery but it's a fresh topic to me...

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "first of their shop_name"? Can a client have only one active shop?

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your `WHERE` clause to your `ON` condition:

```
Select     C.Name,
           S.shop_name
From       Clients As C
Left Join  Shops   As S  On  S.id = C.client_id
                         And S.active = 'y'
```

By including the right-hand table of a `LEFT JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause, you are transforming the `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. It does this because the `WHERE` filter is executed *after* the `LEFT JOIN` has completed, thus filtering out the `NULL` results you would have received.